# Date.Now() in .conf files

Tags: nginx

How would I get the current time in .conf files? I know in javascript it is `Date.now()`, so how would I do it in .conf files? I'm using [this code](https://github.com/binary-person/womginx/blob/master/nginx.conf#L302), and as you can see on line 302, I need it to make the script `/wombat-handler.js?currentTime`, and I want to replace `currentTime` with the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$msec`. See the [list of Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), which can be used for requests/responses.

```
location /get-time { 
  add_header X-msec         $msec;
  add_header X-time_iso8601 $time_iso8601;
  add_header X-time_local   $time_local;
  add_header X-date_gmt     $date_gmt;
  add_header X-date_local   $date_local;

  return 200;
}
```

```sh
$ curl -kI https://example.com/get-time

X-msec: 1638933676.958
X-time_iso8601: 2021-12-07T22:21:16-05:00
X-time_local: 07/Dec/2021:22:21:16 -0500
X-date_gmt: Wednesday, 08-Dec-2021 03:21:16 GMT
X-date_local: Tuesday, 07-Dec-2021 22:21:16 EST
```